# Linkedin REST API - likes and comments

Tags: api, rest, linkedin-api

We are using Linkedin REST API and we need to get the number of likes and comments from owned companies updates. The method get-updates always returns the last 3 likes/comments and also the total is 3, even if you have more than 3. So in order to get all the likes/comments of the updates we have to make a query to each update because that way we get all the likes/comments.   But this is not a good method because if I have 100 updates then I have to do 101 api calls and a user has a limit of 700 per day, so they are very easily get depleted. We really find it hard to believe there is no way your API doesn't solve the n+1 problem. So how can it be done? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you hit this URL -> "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/company-statistics", provided if you have the id of the company page.

you can get the likes,clicks,impressions,engagement,shares,comments in month break up wise.
For more info 
[LinkedIn API Company statistics data](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#statistics)